# Vaadin 14: Close Buffered editor in Grid

Tags: vaadin-grid, vaadin14

I use the buffered editor mode in a bean grid like the first example on the Vaadin Java example page [editor-link](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid/java-examples/grid-editor)

The only difference with the example code is that I'll persist the adapted bean in the database in the `editor.addSaveListener()`.

After saving the data the editor remains open.[image: editer-open] What's the recommended way to close this buffered editor? A `grid.refreshItem(item)` or `grid.refreshAll()` after the `editor.save()` closes the editor but the edit button is not clickable afterwards. The id of the entity remains the same before/after persisting the entity, it's just an update of the entity.

Comment: I suspect that the following happens

You persist the bean to database, and that will produce a new entity instance.

Your edit button will try to open Editor with reference to different entity instance than is in the `DataProvider` backing the Grid. Thus editor wont open as there is no bean matching. Which DataProvider you use?

Comment: I use the ListDataProvider. It's an edit button, so it doesn't create a new entity instance, after persisting the entity, the id keeps the same. So when I don't add grid.refreshAll(), the editor remains open like the printscreen above. But when I refresh the grid, the editor will close but the edit button of that same record isn't clickable anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I know that it is a bit late, but because I also had the same problem and also some times the edit button got disappeared, after hours of try and error, finally I managed to deal with it: I added the line: **grid.setItems(items)** so as to force the grid to rebuild the rows:

```
editor.save();
grid.setItems(items);
grid.getDataProvider().refreshAll();
```